# RESTEasy CDI on Tomcat 7 Exceptions on deployment

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, resteasy

I'm trying to deploy a web application on Tomcat 7.0 using RESTEasy 3.0.6 for RESTful service support.  However, when I try and deploy the application, I get the following Exception:

```
2014-04-09 11:25:27 DEBUG CdiInjectorFactory:68 - Doing a lookup for BeanManager in java:comp/BeanManager
2014-04-09 11:25:27 DEBUG CdiInjectorFactory:68 - Unable to obtain BeanManager from java:comp/BeanManager
2014-04-09 11:25:27 DEBUG CdiInjectorFactory:68 - Doing a lookup for BeanManager in java:app/BeanManager
2014-04-09 11:25:27 DEBUG CdiInjectorFactory:68 - Unable to obtain BeanManager from java:app/BeanManager
2014-04-09 11:25:27 DEBUG CdiInjectorFactory:75 - Not able to access CDI Object, class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.lookupBeanManagerCDIUtil(CdiInjectorFactory.java:201)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.lookupBeanManager(CdiInjectorFactory.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.<init>(CdiInjectorFactory.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:148)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Apr 09, 2014 11:25:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate InjectorFactory implementation.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:156)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to lookup BeanManager.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.lookupBeanManager(CdiInjectorFactory.java:174)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.<init>(CdiInjectorFactory.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:148)
    ... 10 more
```

I've followed [the instructions](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasy-CDIIntegration) on how to incorporate RESTEasy-CDI into my Maven build, and I see the WAR is being built correctly.  However, I still see the Exceptions when I deploy.

The relevant portions of my `web.xml` file look like this:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ConversationPropagationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ConversationPropagationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <resource-env-ref>
    <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.myapp.web.rest.JaxRsActivator</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Any idea what might be causing this or how to get around this error?  At this point, it is basically a show-stopper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  It was merely a servlet listener ordering problem.  I was initializing RESTEasy prior to initializing CDI.

Comment: What did you change to make it work? I have the same problem on Jetty.

Comment: I moved the org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener to before the ResteasyBootstrap listener.